# Filter the data which has delimiter in the ceteria

Tags: split

I am looking to filter the data in Excel CSV file and copy it separately but in my filter criteria I have delimiter. For an example.

```
  List             Field          Description
1 ABC|BCA|CAN      Realtime       Trading status
2 ABC|BCA|CAN      Historical     Temporary Stoppage
3 GBC|NTO          Realtime       Suspension
```

Looking for output like this doing it python script

```
List      Field          Description
ABC       Realtime       Trading status
BCA       Realtime       Trading status
CAN       Realtime       Trading status
ABC       Historical     Temporary Stoppage
BCA       Historical     Temporary Stoppage
CAN       Historical     Temporary Stoppage
GBC       Realtime       Suspension
NTO       Realtime       Suspension
```

Not sure how to use the split function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for python? To duplicate the rows based on the field 'List' you have to split it with the delimiter "|" and than use explode():

```
import pandas as pd

# read the csv into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\s{2,}')

# split the 'List' column into separate rows
df = df.assign(List=df['List'].str.split('|')).explode('List')

# display the transformed dataframe
print(df)
```

The generated output looks like this:

```
  List       Field         Description
0  ABC    Realtime      Trading status
0  BCA    Realtime      Trading status
0  CAN    Realtime      Trading status
1  ABC  Historical  Temporary Stoppage
1  BCA  Historical  Temporary Stoppage
1  CAN  Historical  Temporary Stoppage
2  GBC    Realtime          Suspension
2  NTO    Realtime          Suspension
```